# Will a mini-ITX board fit in a micro-ATX case?

Tags: power-supply, compatibility, computer-building

For example, this kind of case:

https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16811353061&ignorebbr=1

and this kind of board:

https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813128983&ignorebbr=1

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (hardware shopping). Please read [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask). Try [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).  but please first read [What is required for a question to be 'high quality'?"](http://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/205/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-be-high-quality).

Comment: I won't bother with voting to open this question because the specifications of the case cleary indicate in plain language what size motherboards it supports.  **Motherboard Compatibility: [Micro ATX](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/MicroATX) / ATX** vs [Mini-ATX](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini_ATX)

Comment: Point Blank: The case you picked out does not support the motherboard you picked out. I determine this 100% by reading the specifications of the motherboard and the case

Comment: Your motherboard is: 6.7" x 6.7" and your case has standoffs for 9.6"× 9.6" for 12" × 9.6" so you would have no way to install the motherboard.

Comment: I know it seems like an idiotic question, but I only ask because the boss who asked me to pick these parts insisted that as long as the board isn't too big it'll be fine. Maybe those standoff dimensions will convince him otherwise, thanks